# Stripe Connected HTML/CSS button for already connected users

Tags: html, css, angular, stripe-payments, user-experience

I am using [stripe connect](https://stripe.com/docs/connect) with .Net and Angular to build an e-learning marketplace where sellers (teachers) can register their bank accounts [using OAuth with Express accounts](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/oauth-express-accounts#token-request)

When the user (seller) didn't link his bank account to the stripe I am showing the button [as follows](https://codepen.io/stripe-connect/pen/BaQNbjK)

```
.stripe-connect {
  background: #635bff;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 38px;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 180px;

  border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;

  user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;

  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
...more
```

But I didn't find any example of a **HTML/CSS template** when the user is already connected, and you could have the possibility to edit/remove stripe connect considering the UI/UX.

I couldn't find it on their documentation, is there anyone that have any **HTML/CSS design for edit/remove stripe connect**?

Comment: Yeah seems Stripe doesn't have example for edit/remove. I guess you would need to design one yourself

Comment: @orakaro looks like they have the delete, but not edit functionality as well. I am changing the button to "disconect from stripe"
The problem I see is that you can't edit and you can't see what are the bank accounts you have connected with stripe